# Using return output from one function to another in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I pass the `Return Output` from one function to another.

#### Function1

```
def replaceClean(text)
```

this function basically clean the data and special characters.

#### Function2

```
RenamerSTD(text)
```

this function should get the return output from `Function1` and process then.

#### Examples:

```
def replaceClean(text):
    for ch in [')','(','-','/','\\','.']:
        if ch in text:

            text = text.replace(ch,"")

    for ch in ['<']:
        if ch in text:
            text = text.replace(ch,"_LessThan_")

    for ch in ['>']:
        if ch in text:
            text = text.replace(ch,"_GreaterThan_")



    for ch in ['__']:
        if ch in text:
            text = text.replace(ch,"_")

    print text # this should be return I know. but I want to pass this to function RenamerSTD

def RenamerSTD(text1):

    if len(text1 ) > 10:
        splitted = text1.split("_")

        #ss= [items[:3] for items in splitted]
        my_new_list = []
        for item in splitted:
            ss= item[:2] #if len(item) >= 4 else item[:2]

            my_new_list.append(str(ss))

        print '_'.join(my_new_list)

replaceClean(RenamerSTD(text))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as was intimated in your example:

```
RenamerSTD(replaceClean(text))
```

In which case it is the responsibilty of the caller to make the sub-call. Or you can simply have `RenamerSTD` call `replaceClean` like:

```
def replaceClean(text):
    ...
    return text

def RenamerSTD(text1):
    text1 = replaceClean(text1)
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks very much..! it works. Learn this new thing today. Happy

Comment: how to deal with Error `global name 'text' is not defined`.